# Disable on click highlight of InfoWindows?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Is there any way to disable the highlight effect that comes when user clicks on a `InfoWindow` in the new `Mapsv2 Api` for Android?

This is an issue with both the `getIfoContent()` and the `getInfoWindow()` methods. With the `getInfoWindow()` its the text which highlights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words "YOU CANT" .

because as per documentation "An info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window."

So, in short u can't handle any events on infowindow other than "OnInfoWindowClickListener"

For more check "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker".

Comment: I recently had to revisit this issue and came to the same conclusion. The only workaround would be to use a Custom implementation of some sort.